# Прокрутка панели колёсиком под моно в линуксе

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, vb.net, mono

Есть панель с `AutoScroll = True`. В Windows её можно скроллить за скроллбар, а также просто прокручивая колёсико мышки. Но если ту же программу запустить в линуксе под mono, то полоса прокрутки отображается и функционирует, а вот прокрутка при помощи колёсика не работает. Как сделать, чтобы можно было прокручивать панель колёсиком?

```vb
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Pnl As New Panel With {.Parent = Me, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .AutoScroll = True}
    Pnl.Controls.Add(New PictureBox With {.Height = Pnl.Height / 2 + 10, .Dock = DockStyle.Top, .BackColor = Color.Red})
    Pnl.Controls.Add(New PictureBox With {.Height = Pnl.Height / 2 + 10, .Dock = DockStyle.Top, .BackColor = Color.Blue})
  End Sub
End Class
```

PS: Для запуска vb.net-приложений под моно следует установить `mono-vbnc`.

PPS: Linux Mint 18 в VirtualBox.

Comment: А если на событие MouseWheel подписаться и руками дернуть за скрол? Это событие доступно только в коде, в конструкторе нет.

Comment: @rdorn, вроде уж совсем костыли? В винде приложению не помешает? И да, а как программно дёрнуть скролл?

Comment: не не вариант. дернуть так можно, но мешает.

Comment: можно еще переопределить OnMouseWheel(), но я не знаю способа определить на чем запущено приложение, во всяком случае еще не копал в эту сторону

Comment: @rdorn, я видел способ - там в рантайме можно существование класса определённого проверить.

Comment: тогда можно попробовать, костыль - однозначно, но я других вариантов не вижу. Просто поставить условие, если ос - Win - вызываем базовую реализацию, если нет - свою.

Comment: @rdorn, там ещё косяк есть - цифровой блок клавиатуры не работает... Точнее, не всегда работает. Бррррр...